# Custom function in cloudformation does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

I need to invoke lambda in cloud formation:

Here is my yaml template:

```
#test-custom-func
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Parameters:
  project:
    Description: project
    Type: String
    ConstraintDescription: Any string
  EnvironmentApp:
    Description: EnvironmentApp
    Type: String
    ConstraintDescription: Any string
Description: ddddd
Resources:
  removeBucket:
    Type: Custom::Myfunction
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxx:function:test1
```

and here is the test lambda function:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
// TODO implement
console.log("rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr");
callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda');
};
```

As you see everything is very basic. When I run the yaml stack it is never created and stays in create in progress status and after long it will fail.

Am I missing anything in using custom function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly send a response to CloudFormation rather than using the `callback` method.

Insert this snippet I've found [in the doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-custom-resources-lambda-lookup-amiids.html) into your code:

```
// Send response to the pre-signed S3 URL 
function sendResponse(event, context, responseStatus, responseData) {

    var responseBody = JSON.stringify({
        Status: responseStatus,
        Reason: "See the details in CloudWatch Log Stream: " + context.logStreamName,
        PhysicalResourceId: context.logStreamName,
        StackId: event.StackId,
        RequestId: event.RequestId,
        LogicalResourceId: event.LogicalResourceId,
        Data: responseData
    });

    console.log("RESPONSE BODY:\n", responseBody);

    var https = require("https");
    var url = require("url");

    var parsedUrl = url.parse(event.ResponseURL);
    var options = {
        hostname: parsedUrl.hostname,
        port: 443,
        path: parsedUrl.path,
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            "content-type": "",
            "content-length": responseBody.length
        }
    };

    console.log("SENDING RESPONSE...\n");

    var request = https.request(options, function(response) {
        console.log("STATUS: " + response.statusCode);
        console.log("HEADERS: " + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
        // Tell AWS Lambda that the function execution is done  
        context.done();
    });

    request.on("error", function(error) {
        console.log("sendResponse Error:" + error);
        // Tell AWS Lambda that the function execution is done  
        context.done();
    });

    // write data to request body
    request.write(responseBody);
    request.end();
}
```

And invoke the `sendResponse` when your logic is completed as follow:

```
var responseStatus = "SUCCESS";
var responseData = {};
sendResponse(event, context, responseStatus, responseData);
```